# Set figure options for Python with knitr

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, r-markdown, knitr

I have a `knitr` document (either Rmd or Rnw) in which I want to generate some output with R and some with Python. However, I'm not able to change the figure options that are being used in Python.

Specifically, if I use `knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = ..., fig.height = ...)` **before** the first Python chunk, then these options are used for **all** subsequent Python plots. But I don't seem to be able to change the figure options afterwards in order to generate different plots with different figure options.

In the R/Markdown document (`py.Rmd`) below I include a minimal example. After the Python setup chunk neither the explicit `knitr::opts_chunk$set()` nor the options of the individual `line` and `bar` chunks are honored.

````
--- 
title: 'Figure options for Python with knitr'
output: html_document
---

These figure options work:

```{r opts}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 6, fig.height = 5)
```

Python setup works:

```{python setup}
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
d = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]})
```

Plots work but all figure options are ignored:

```{r opts2}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 2, fig.height = 6)
```

```{python line, fig.width = 2, fig.height = 6}
d.plot.line(x = 'x', y = 'y')
plt.show()
```

```{python bar, fig.width = 6, fig.height = 2}
d.plot.bar(x = 'x', y = 'y')
plt.show()
```
````

Using `rmarkdown::render("py.Rmd")` in R 4.2.1 with `knitr` 1.42, `rmarkdown` 2.20 and `reticulate` 1.28 I get the following output where both figures are 6 x 5 and not 2 x 6 or 6 x 2.

[image: Rendered py.Rmd]

Comment: I'm not sure how opts_chunk are evaluated, but it is usually recommended to have a chunk named setup for this kind of configuration. This chunk is special as it is loaded first I think. Have you tried it specifying it at the beginning of the document  for R and not for a python chunk?

Comment: Yes. The naming is not the issue. It's really whether the `opts_chunk` are called prior to Python or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you use plot via your dataframe you can specify figsize as an argument:

```
d.plot.bar(x = "x", y = "y", figsize = [2,6])
```

Comment: Thanks! For some of the plots in my actual document I can set `figsize` easily but for others (using multiple suplots generated by another package) I can not. Hence it would still be good if I could set it from the `knitr` side somehow.